# Writing RTSP player for iOS, what libraries are available

Tags: ios, rtsp

Currently iOS only supports HTTP streaming, which is not suitable for nonbuffered live streams (you have to have about 30 seconds of video pre-buffered as opposed to about 1 second).

If I wanted to write an RTSP play for iOS would I be starting from absolute scratch? or are there libraries (3rd party or whatever) to aid in development of an RTSP player for iOS.

Comment: Any luck in getting this done ?

Comment: not yet. To get around the issue, we stream a buffered version to the ipad/iphone. It's not the best solution, but most of our clients use blackberry anyway.